# In parallel processing, how to make each processor execute a block of program using mathematica

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mathematica-8

I want to write a block of C code and send it to every processor to execute it

Is that possible using mathematica?

using gateway to link C with mathematica or what ever

thank you all .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is, but you will need to distribute your function over the CPUs in the c code. By default, Mathematica isn't able to detect that your functions are atomic.

Have you checked out http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkDeveloperGuide-Unix.html ?

EDIT: If you are very certain you want to do this check out http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelTable.html . It doesn't work particularly well with my c++, thats why I didn't recommend it :-).

Comment: thank you, that really helps me out .. :)

but I want the mathematica part that allows me to execute my code distributed on the cores

thank again .. :)